# ¿Soap puede devolver resutados que no esten en una etiquerta "result"?

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Pongo las partes que creo que son relevantes, ya me decís si echáis algo en falta:
tengo esto en mi wsdl:

```
            <xsd:element name="holaMundo">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="nombre" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="holaMundoResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="holaMundoResult" type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element name="anio" type="xsd:int" />
                        <xsd:element name="mes" type="xsd:int" />
                        <xsd:element name="dia" type="xsd:int" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
```

En mi controlador tengo:

```
class SoapRickServerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {        
        $options = ['uri' => env('URI_SOAP_CLIENT_ALT')];
        $url = "http://192.168.50.1/soap/ric?wsdl";
        $server = new \SoapServer($url, $options);
        $server->setClass(Soap\ServerWS::class);
        $server->handle();
    }
```

y este es mi servicio:

```
class ServerWS
{
    public function __construct()    {    }

    public function holaMundo($nombre)
    {
        $r = new stdClass();

        $r->holaMundoResult = 2;
        $r->anio = 1;
        $r->mes = 1;
        $r->dia = 1;

        return $r;
```

esta es mi peticion:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="htt ...
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rick:holaMundo>
         <nombre>paco</nombre>
      </rick:holaMundo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

¡pero!!
en la respuesta solo aparece el holamundoresut

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://s... ...
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:holaMundoResponse xsi:type="ns1:holaMundoResponse">
         <holaMundoResult xsi:type="xsd:string">2</holaMundoResult>
      </ns1:holaMundoResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

y yo lo que quero es devolver varios parametrios y que que el nombre no tenga que ser exactamente el de la llamada+result.

¿Es posible hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: bueno, si el codigo es tal cual lo tienes ... parece estar bien... no veo ningun problema con el codigo, este deberia devolver las 4 propiedades, lo unico que se me ocurre que puede estar pasando es un problema de cache si tiene caches en el servidor deberias limpiarlo, otra cosa que se me ocurra es lo que hay despues del metodo holaMundo si haces alguna manipulacion para convertirlo en el xml SOAP... puede estar afectando ...

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que era eso.
hoy cuando he arrancado funcionaba sin mas.

Comment: evalua desactivar o como desactivar el cache para el consumo de tu API ... si los datos son dinamicos y en tiempo real, el cache te va a dar problemas ...

Comment: Ok en local lo soluciono con un systemctl restart apache2, asi que puedo dar la cuestión por solucionada.
Si quieres ponme como respuesta lo del systemctl u otra manera que uses tu y/o algo mas sobre desactivar la cache y te selecciono la respuesta como "mejor respuesta" :D muchas gracias. Mirare lo de la cache.

Comment: Listo, ya te agregue la respuesta de todas las cosas que debeiras hacer y considerar cuando haces debug de tu sistema entorno al cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay varias cosas que pueden estar afectando temporalmente la ejecución de tu versión y que al final cuando intentes correr la aplicación y el consumo de Apis entregue una estructura previa o diferente; todo esto está asociado al cache de las consultas y de PHP:

***En el Backend:***

En apache via `Virtual Host`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 01:00:00 GMT"
</VirtualHost>
```

Via `.htaccess`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 21 Oct 2015 01:00:00 GMT"
</VirtualHost>
```

Primero el `php.ini` puedes intentar con:

```
apc.enabled=0
```

o en el `user.ini`:

```
apc.enabled=0
```

Nota: recuerda que cualquier cambio en las configuraciones requiere reiniciar el servicio apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

***En el Frontend:***

Si estás intentando detener el almacenamiento en caché de tus páginas web usando PHP tambien puedes, uso el siguiente código, Minimiza el almacenamiento en caché para que el área de administración siempre muestre las últimas estadísticas

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); //cambialo a tu nesecidad
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Si bien nada es realmente una prueba completa, ya que muchos archivos CSS y otros archivos JS se almacenan en caché independientemente de PHP y requieren una actualización para mostrarse una vez actualizados, también hay otras formas de evitar esto.

Un ejemplo que uso es hacer un hash del archivo (usando php):

```
$specific_page = '/assets/javascripts/pages/javascript.js';
if(file_exists($specific_page)) {
    $html .= '<script src="'.$specific_page.'?v='.hash_file('crc32',$specific_page).'"></script>';
}
```

Esto mantendrá el archivo en caché hasta que se cambie el archivo. Cuando se cambia el archivo, cambia el hash y, por lo tanto, encontrará el nuevo archivo actualizado (ya que técnicamente la URL ha cambiado).

Nuevamente, nada es realmente una prueba completa para evitar el almacenamiento en caché en el lado del cliente, estas son bases que deben ir probando y aplicando incluso dentro de tus metodos de debug.